# How do I migrate the content of a book?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a Drupal 7 site I want to upgrade to Drupal 8. I take this occasion to rethink the structure and theming, but I would like to extract/copy/move/import the book content from the original site into the new one. (I cannot use Drush.)

I can export the book content using a view. How do I add the book structure? I found a relationship to parent, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Look into the migration API in Drupal 8.

Comment: I did, but I could not find which part is relevant to this question.